# Use a Field in main Table to Update a Field in Another Table in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, updates, lookup

I have three tables in Access DB, "tbl_BO" which is linked to Excel sheet which is updated every monday, "tbl_KPI1" and "tbl_KPI2. Every table has field called "CW", means calendar week. "tbl_BO" has all the same fields which has other two tables.

I want to run a macro by clicking a buttom which does the following: For example for "tbl_KPI1".
Lookup "CW" from last week (in this case 2016.44) in "tbl_BO", match it with "CW" of "tbl_KPI1", and update the field "115p".

Below, I have written a code, which is running all the values in that field ("115p"). But as I said I want to update the values only from last week (ISO week)

```
Public Function Update()
   DoCmd.SetWarnings False

   DoCmd.RunSQL "Update tbl_KPI1 INNER JOIN tbl_BO " & _
   "ON tbl_KPI1.CW = tbl_BO.CW " & _
   "SET tbl_KPI1.115p = [tbl_BO].[115p] "

     'Here come codes to update the fields of other tables, same logic       

   DoCmd.SetWarnings True

   End Function
```

And my ISO week code is:

```
Function ISOweek(ByVal Dat As Date)

ISOweek = Int((Dat - Weekday(Dat, vbMonday) + 11 - _
DateValue("jan 01," & Year(Dat + 4 - Weekday(Dat, vbMonday)))) / 7)

End Function
```

How can I make a combination of both codes in order to achieve what I want. Or any ideas how to do it? Thanks.
[image]